# Add/Remove value in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have a question about adding and removing value from a document. For example, I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537267b7186f521c07d63af1"),
    "users" : [ 
        "53725f9d186f521d07d63af1",
        "51725f9d186f521d07d33ah1"
    ]
}
```

I want to 1) remove "53725f9d186f521d07d63af1" from the users list, 2) add a new user to the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put more code to understand what you want to do !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$pull` to remove `53725f9d186f521d07d63af1`:

```
$collection->update(
  array('_id' => new MongoId('537267b7186f521c07d63af1')),   // _id of the document
  array('$pull' =>
    array('users' => new MongoId('53725f9d186f521d07d63af1') // id to be removed
  )
);
```

And `$addToSet` to add a new id:

```
$collection->update(
  array('_id' => new MongoId('537267b7186f521c07d63af1')),   // _id of the document
  array('$addToSet' =>
    array('users' => new MongoId('51725f9d186f521d07d33ah1') // id to be added
  )
);
```